# How to export dynamic columns to CSV using Scrapy CsvItemExporter

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm having the scrapy spider which scraps details from the website. It works well for fixed Item fields. It also extracts the dynamic fields from the website, but it did not add all the extracted dynamic fields to an output CSV file.

To export records to CSV, I'm using `CsvItemExporter`.

Find the Below Item class for Dynamic fields

```
class MortgageInfoItem(scrapy.Item):
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    if key not in self.fields:
        if "date" in key:
            self.fields[key] = scrapy.Field(serializer=serialize_date)
        else:
            self.fields[key] = scrapy.Field(serializer=serialize_text)
    self._values[key] = value
```

The fields may vary for each record. For example, the first record has owner1 and owner2, next record has owner1, owner2 and owner3 like this.

So finally I need the CSV file which has all the owner information. (ex. owner1, owner2, owner3, ...)

Find the below class for csv exporter

```
class MultiCSVItemPipeline(object):
CSVDir = 'output' + settings.DIRECTORY
file_name = "MortGage_info"
max_columns = 0

def __init__(self):
    dispatcher.connect(self.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
    dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)

def spider_opened(self, spider):
    self.file = open(self.CSVDir + self.file_name + '.csv', 'w+b')
    self.exporters = CsvItemExporter(self.file)
    self.exporters.start_exporting()

def spider_closed(self, spider):
    self.exporters.finish_exporting()
    self.file.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.exporters.export_item(item)
    return item
```

Please help me to export all the fields to CSV file using `CsvItemExporter`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provided your code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have just now added my code

Comment: If fields vary from record to record but all possible fields are known beforehand, use [FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#std:setting-FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS). Otherwise, subclass the built-in CSV feed exported and modify it so that it can handle your use case.

Comment: For example one record has 2 owners and other record has only one users.So we cant identify the maximum number of owners before execution to finalize the column names. So as of now to over come this i have set maximum number of owners as 10 @Gallaecio